# how to avoid deposit fees / transaction fees when buying bitcoin

Tags: transaction-fees

I've looked at Coinbase and CEX.io, and both have a deposit limit of $300.

For Coinbase it is $11.51 deposit transaction fee on a deposit of $300, or 3.84%, which is huuge.

For CEX.io, it is a $11.14 deposit transaction fee on a deposit of $300, or 3.71%, which is still huge.

Can anyone recommend a service which allows me to:

1. deposit more than $300 at a time (ideally up to $3300 for the price of 1 bitcoin)
2. receive a deposit transaction fee far less than 3%?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase has a much larger limit if you verify yourself.  For instance, on Coinbase I have $5000/week limit.  And I belive you can get up to $1M limit with enough paperwork.

Bitfinex offers a .1% fee or $20 (whichever is higher) so for $3300 that would be .6% fee with the $20 minimum.  For $300 though, that's 6.6%

I'm not sure where you get $11.51 for $300 at CB.  I just attempted to buy $300 and it was only going to charge me $304.47, which is a 1.49% fee.  There's the same 1.49% on a $5000 purchase.  They do have a minimum, which appears to be $0.99 < $50, $1.99 < $100, $2.99 < $202, and after that it's 1.49%

EDIT: Oh, I see.. You're talking AUD, not USD.  Not sure what the rate is there.  FYI, in the future it's best to specify currency symbol if you're talking about Dollars and not USD.

According to this page:

https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/2109597-buy-sell-bank-transfer-fees

3.99% is the base, but in the US they wave some fees depending on the payment type.  It appears that in AU they only allow Credit Card purchases, and not wire or EFT.  That kind of sucks for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use p2p exchange services such as [Bisq](https://bitsquare.io/), PAXFUL or [Localbitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/).

Comment: What are the security implications of using these exchanges please Gary?

Comment: Every exchange has its own security measurement, you should read them before you use them. In general, I'd say comparing to buying stuff off Craigslist or ebay, p2p exchanges are much more secure, but it depends on individuals, which is why centralized exchanges charge more, they do offer a more consistent security layer.